# Weebly: After clicking on "Manage" button redirects to wrong url

Tags: weebly

We have developed a weebly app for our product. After installation when clicking on "Manage" button it redirects to another url. Not the url we have defined in manifest.json

```
 "manage_app_url": "https://...com/",
```

We have cleared the **cache of the browser**. Tried on **incognito** also. But didn't get the expected URL. Could anyone give any solution?

Answer (score 0):

It might help if you posted the whole manifest, but for reference, here is a working example:

```
{
  "manifest": "1",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "client_id" : "111111111",
  "callback_url" : "https://www.example.com/path/to/callback",
  "scopes": ["read:site", "write:site"],
  "manage_app_url": "https://www.example.com/",
  "oauth_final_destination" : "manage",
  "locale": {
     "default": "en-us",
     "supported": ["en-us"]
  },
  "webhooks": {
     "callback_url": "https://www.example.com/path/to/webhooks",
     "events": ["app.uninstall", "site.publish", "site.delete"]
  },
  "snippet": "files/assets/snippet.tpl"
}
```

> Note: the snippet.tpl is empty in my case, and is added via API.

If you can use this, and just replace the `client_id, callback_url, manage_app_url & callback_url` and it is NOT working it is possible something else is going on and you may want to reach out to the Weebly Dev's.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have checked after 5-6 hours. Then it was ok. May be caching issue or server took some time to apply the change.